# pronunciation of は

Tags: pronunciation

Hello I'm a beginner and I'm wondering when to use the right pronunciation of は, because sometimes it's pronounced "ha" and sometimes "wa".

Answer (score 3):

は is pronounced as 'ha' when used as part of a word and 'wa' when used as a particle.

eg. 今日は早く帰ります。

きょう　**は**　**は**やく　かえります。
kyou  **wa** **ha**yaku kaerimasu.

(Rough translation : Today i'll go home early.)
はな - hana(flower)
はる - haru(spring)